# Multiple firewalls in symfony2

Tags: php, security, symfony

I have a problem with my security configuration in symfony2. I need two firewalls for two different user entity.

Here are my configuration files:

security.yml:

```
security:
    encoders:
        entity_owner:
            class: Pisteur\CoreBundle\Entity\OwnerAccount
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: false
        entity_business:
            class: Pisteur\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessOwner
            algorithm: sha512
            iterations: 5000
            encode_as_base64: false
    providers:
        entity_owner:
            name: entity_owner
            entity:
                class: Pisteur\CoreBundle\Entity\OwnerAccount
                property: username
        entity_business:
            name: entity_business
            entity:
                class: Pisteur\BusinessBundle\Entity\BusinessOwner
                property: username
    firewalls:
        entity_business:
            pattern: ^/business
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: /business/login_check
                login_path: /business/login
                default_target_path: /business/dashboard
            provider: entity_business
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /business/login
        entity_owner:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                default_target_path: /dashboard
            provider: entity_owner
            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /login
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_BUSINESS]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/business/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/account, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/dashboard, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/business/dashboard, roles: ROLE_BUSINESS }
        - { path: ^/_internal, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, ip: 127.0.0.1 }
```

Here are all my routings:

```
security_login:
    pattern:  /login
    defaults: { _controller: "PisteurSecurityBundle:Security:login" }
    requirements: { _method: get }

login_check:
    pattern: /login_check

business_security_login:
    pattern:  /business/login
    defaults: { _controller: "PisteurSecurityBundle:BusinessSecurity:login" }
    requirements: { _method: get }

business_login_check:
    pattern: /business/login_check

logout:
    pattern: /logout
```

Login form for OwnerAccount:

```
<form id="login-form" action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
            <label><input id="username" type="text" name="_username" /></label>
            <label><input id="password" type="password" name="_password" /></label>
            <button class="btn custom large orange-button" type="submit" id="login-button">{% trans from "login" %}login{% endtrans %}</button>
 </form>
```

Login form for BusinessOwner:

```
<form id="login-form" action="{{ path('business_login_check') }}" method="post">
            <label><input id="username" type="text" name="_username" /></label>
            <label><input id="password" type="password" name="_password" /></label>
            <button class="btn custom large orange-button" type="submit" id="login-button">{% trans from "login" %}login{% endtrans %}</button>
</form>
```

When I login with the OwnerAccount form, it works and redirect my to /dashboard.
When I login with the BusinessOwner form, it does not work and redirect to /login (should be /business/login) with the error "BadCredentials"

I'm not sure why but it seems that only the entity_owner is used (because it redirect to /login from the /business/login)

Is that something wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Your entity_business pattern is matched by your entity_owner pattern, (ie. ^/business is matched by ^/). I think they have to be completely separate patterns to work properly.

Comment: It might be true. I'm not really good with regex. What would be the regex to match "^/" but not "^/business" for my entity_owner? Thank you

Comment: Option 1: Try something like ^/(?!business) for the entity_owner pattern.  Option 2: Change the entity_owner pattern to ^/owner, and make the main page redirect to /owner.

Comment: You should write it as an official answer. I'll test it later and if it works I'll mark your answer as the good one.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like `^/(?!business)` for the entity_owner pattern, this may prevent the entity_owner pattern from matching the entity_business pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Move all of your owner resources to /owner. Change the entity_owner pattern to `^/owner`, and make the main page redirect to /owner.